# How to set up authentication for the personal userdir in Apache?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, authentication

I set up authentication on my personal `public_html` in my `home` dir, but it takes no effect. Ie., I should get a pop-up asking for my credentials, but this doesn't happen. The authentication worked fine with a directory in the server's root directory, and it worked ok. Now I'm restructuring the server.

Here are some more details. There are a few side problems and questions related to the config file, which I put **in bold**.

- I have the main HTTP directory in `/var/www/html` and the same for HTTPS.
- There's only one file there, `index.html` with a link to my personal `~tomas` URL. It works fine. I'm using the `userdir` mod for mapping `~tomas`.
- I also have a personal `cgi-bin` directory, and the CGIs work ok, but I would like the URL `~tomas/cgi-bin` **to show the directory listing**, which doesn't work for some reason and I get 403 Forbidden.
- I want to have the main directory available in both HTTPS and HTTP and with no authorisation. But once the client requests one of the personal `public_html` directories through `~user`, the access should be authenticated and **the authentication should take place over HTTPS**. So HTTP needs to switch to HTTPS. I've already set up and tested HTTPS facilities, but have not yet set up any enforcement in this context. I have no FQDN if it matters.

**The main question is nevertheless, how to get the authentication itself work for `~user`, even over HTTP.**

I put all the configs in `userdir.conf` and I *guess* the problem is with using the wildcard in `/home/*/public_html`.

Here's the `userdir.conf`.

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        UserDir "public_html"
        UserDir disabled
        UserDir enabled tomas

        <Directory "/home/*/public_html">
                AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
                Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
                <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
                        Require all granted
                </Limit>
                <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
                        Require all denied
                </LimitExcept>
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Personal HTML"
                AuthUserFile "/usr/share/apache2/passwd/passwords"
                Require valid-user
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        <Directory "/home/*/public_html/cgi-bin">
                Options ExecCGI Indexes
                SetHandler cgi-script
        </Directory>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

If you have any comments on this config file or about my approach to Apache in general, please do comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is the `Limit` directive. The clue is present in the [`<Limit>` Directive section](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limit) of the `core` mod Apache doc page.

> When using `<Limit>` or `<LimitExcept>` directives with the `Require`
>   directive, note that the first `Require` to succeed authorizes the
>   request, regardless of the presence of other `Require` directives.

As it turns out, the first `Require` that matches the case at hand decides how it's processed. With the config from my question, that is:

```
            <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
                    Require all granted
            </Limit>
            <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
                    Require all denied
            </LimitExcept>
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Personal HTML"
            AuthUserFile "/usr/share/apache2/passwd/passwords"
            Require valid-user
```

with a simple GET request, it's the `Require all granted` in the second line of the listing above that does the thing. The `AuthType Basic` and other lines below it are dead code. A right way to go is:

```
            <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
                    AuthType Basic
                    AuthName "Personal HTML"
                    AuthUserFile "/usr/share/apache2/passwd/passwords"
                    Require valid-user
            </Limit>
            <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
                    Require all denied
            </LimitExcept>
```

As an aside, here's a case when the `Limit` directive is ignored.

```
            Require all granted
            <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
                    AuthType Basic
                    AuthName "Personal HTML"
                    AuthUserFile "/usr/share/apache2/passwd/passwords"
                    Require valid-user
            </Limit>
            <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
                    Require all denied
            </LimitExcept>
```

The first line succeeds and authorises the request.